# What are the differences between Elder Sign and Elder Sign: Omens?

Tags: elder-sign

I've played the board game *Elder Sign*. I have read some reviews and seen a gameplay video of *Elder Sign: Omens*, the iOS app based on the board game, but I haven't been able to find info on exactly how similar the two are. I see that they even share the same tag on here, so I'm guessing they are pretty close, but I'd like to know more definitively.

Is *Elder Sign: Omen* basically a straight-up single player version of the board game, or are there some mechanical differences between the two? If so, how do they differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a thread on [BGG discussing the changes](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/7783006#7783006). They are far to numerous to mention all the changes, but some of the most notable are:

- There are no allies.
- Spells are cast after rolling, but don't carry over to other investigators.
- Only 1-4 investigators instead of 1-8
- There are no midnight events.
- Assisting investigators aren't penalized when you fail.
- Monsters are added automatically, you cannot choose where they are placed.

Comment: The base app had Yig and Azathoth. There was also a 3rd one that was locked... I think this was the purchasable Cthulhu expansion, but I could be wrong, as I did not purchase it, and haven't seen it unlock itself during my small bit of gameplay.

Comment: There is a purchasable Cthulhu expansion, yes.  As for the description, this seems complete.  I will note that while I'd prefer to have things like the midnight events and some of the other parts of the board game in the mobile adaptation, what remains still gives much of the same flavor.

Comment: Quick point, it is good to duplicate information in answers rather then just linking. That way if BGG (or any external site) goes down the answer is still useful.

Comment: The random equivalent of mythos cards all seem to be doom tokens or monster-related, but there are adventures that have "at midnight" effects in _Omens_.